# Discord.py , many users react at the same time, causing error so how to solve this problem?

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

**I am making auction bot. So I added bid with reaction. It works great when users react not at the same time. But , when many users react at the same time again and again ( spamming) system can't catch up current value so sometimes it uses old value. How can I solve this problem ? or How can I make queue reaction events**

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
        channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
        user = bot.get_user(payload.user_id)
        try:
            msgMuzayede =await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)

        #Mesajımıza ulaştık buradan embed ettiğim price kısmını kullanalım
        #  
            fields = msgMuzayede.embeds
            embedMsg = fields[0]
            currentValue = embedMsg.fields[0].value
            bet = embedMsg.fields[1].value
            if user.bot == False and embedMsg.fields[5].name != "FINISHED":
                if embedMsg.fields[5].name == "FINISHED":
                #alert = await channel.send("Its Finished")
                #kullanıcın mesajını silme özelliği eklenmeli
                    m=await channel.send("It is finished!!!")
                    await m.delete(delay=15)
                    return
                
                elif payload.emoji.name =="2️⃣":
                    
                    embedMsg.set_field_at(0,name="Price",value=int(currentValue)+(int(bet)*2),inline=True)
                    embedMsg.set_field_at(3,name="Winner",value=user.mention,inline=True)
                    await msgMuzayede.edit(embed=embedMsg)
                elif payload.emoji.name =="3️⃣":
                    

                    embedMsg.set_field_at(0,name="Price",value=int(currentValue)+(int(bet)*3),inline=True)
                    embedMsg.set_field_at(3,name="Winner",value=user.mention,inline=True)
                    await msgMuzayede.edit(embed=embedMsg)
                elif payload.emoji.name =="4️⃣":
                    

                    embedMsg.set_field_at(0,name="Price",value=int(currentValue)+(int(bet)*4),inline=True)
                    embedMsg.set_field_at(3,name="Winner",value=user.mention,inline=True)
                    await msgMuzayede.edit(embed=embedMsg)
                elif payload.emoji.name =="5️⃣":
                    

                    embedMsg.set_field_at(0,name="Price",value=int(currentValue)+(int(bet)*5),inline=True)
                    embedMsg.set_field_at(3,name="Winner",value=user.mention,inline=True)
                    await msgMuzayede.edit(embed=embedMsg)
                elif payload.emoji.name =="6️⃣":
                    

                    embedMsg.set_field_at(0,name="Price",value=int(currentValue)+(int(bet)*6),inline=True)
                    embedMsg.set_field_at(3,name="Winner",value=user.mention,inline=True)
                    await msgMuzayede.edit(embed=embedMsg)
                elif payload.emoji.name =="7️⃣":
                    

                    embedMsg.set_field_at(0,name="Price",value=int(currentValue)+(int(bet)*7),inline=True)
                    embedMsg.set_field_at(3,name="Winner",value=user.mention,inline=True)
                    await msgMuzayede.edit(embed=embedMsg)
                elif payload.emoji.name =="8️⃣":
                    

                    embedMsg.set_field_at(0,name="Price",value=int(currentValue)+(int(bet)*8),inline=True)
                    embedMsg.set_field_at(3,name="Winner",value=user.mention,inline=True)
                    await msgMuzayede.edit(embed=embedMsg)
                elif payload.emoji.name =="9️⃣":
                    

                    embedMsg.set_field_at(0,name="Price",value=int(currentValue)+(int(bet)*9),inline=True)
                    embedMsg.set_field_at(3,name="Winner",value=user.mention,inline=True)
                    await msgMuzayede.edit(embed=embedMsg)
                elif payload.emoji.name =="":
                    

                    embedMsg.set_field_at(0,name="Price",value=int(currentValue)+(int(bet)*10),inline=True)
                    embedMsg.set_field_at(3,name="Winner",value=user.mention,inline=True)
                    await msgMuzayede.edit(embed=embedMsg)
                elif payload.emoji.name =="":
                    

                    embedMsg.set_field_at(0,name="Price",value=int(currentValue)+(int(bet)*100),inline=True)
                    embedMsg.set_field_at(3,name="Winner",value=user.mention,inline=True)
                    await msgMuzayede.edit(embed=embedMsg)
                elif payload.emoji.name =="":
                    

                    embedMsg.set_field_at(0,name="Price",value=int(currentValue)+(int(bet)*1000),inline=True)
                    embedMsg.set_field_at(3,name="Winner",value=user.mention,inline=True)
                    await msgMuzayede.edit(embed=embedMsg)

            time.sleep(1)        
                    
        except Exception as e:
            print("react",e)
```

Comment: Keep track of `currentValue` (and the current winner) locally per... whatever your auctions are rather than trusting to read it from an embed in the message.

Comment: should i use database?

Comment: Depends on your app's requirements. Probably just a global variable will do for starters.

Comment: I think , whats happen when i use local variable or database? on_raw_reaction_add() func. is async so when triggered this function too much it gonna work likely at same time.
Since it is running asynchronously, it starts the other process before one operation ends. It is possible that the new process will use the old value before the other process changes its value.

Comment: I just want to create queue for async function but idk how to do so asked here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help who not help.

You can use bot.wait_for like this:

```
async def reaction_control(message):
     while( True):  #Your condition
          def check (reaction,user):
            return reaction.emoji == ""
          try:
            reaction,user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add",timeout=0.1,check=check)     
          except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pass
          else:

            #Your Code
```